# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'label' drf-yasg

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I am integrating drf-yasq swagger for the first time, Sorry! if my question is silly. I read the doc from here https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html and followed the instructions and end up with `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'label'`. original code is from https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html. please help me where I am lacking:

**Terminal:**

```
 Internal Server Error: /swagger/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
  r . eturn view_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
   return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
  response = self.handle_exception(exc)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 457, in handle_exception
   self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 468, in raise_uncaught_exception
   raise exc
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
   response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/views.py", line 94, in get
   schema = generator.get_schema(request, self.public)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/generators.py", line 254, in get_schema
   paths, prefix = self.get_paths(endpoints, components, request, public)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/generators.py", line 412, in get_paths
   operation = self.get_operation(view, path, prefix, method, components, request)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/generators.py", line 454, in get_operation
   operation = view_inspector.get_operation(operation_keys)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/view.py", line 45, in get_operation
   responses = self.get_responses()
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/view.py", line 180, in get_responses
   response_serializers = self.get_response_serializers()
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/view.py", line 235, in get_response_serializers
   responses = self.get_default_responses()
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/view.py", line 211, in get_default_responses
   default_schema = self.serializer_to_schema(default_schema) or ''
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/base.py", line 446, in serializer_to_schema
   self.field_inspectors, 'get_schema', serializer, {'field_inspectors': 
   self.field_inspectors}
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/base.py", line 118, in probe_inspectors
   result = method(obj, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
    packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/field.py", line 42, in get_schema
    return self.probe_field_inspectors(serializer, openapi.Schema, self.use_definitions)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
    packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/base.py", line 238, in probe_field_inspectors
    swagger_object_type=swagger_object_type, use_references=use_references, **kwargs
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
     packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/base.py", line 118, in probe_inspectors
     result = method(obj, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
     packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/field.py", line 83, in field_to_swagger_object
     SwaggerType, ChildSwaggerType = self._get_partial_types(field, swagger_object_type, 
     use_references, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/admin/Desktop/food-delivery-app-19083590-python/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
     packages/drf_yasg/inspectors/base.py", line 273, in _get_partial_types
     title = force_real_str(field.label) if field.label else None
 AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'label'
 HTTP GET /swagger/?format=openapi 500 [2.48, 127.0.0.1:51305]
```

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
         ...
         'drf_yasg',
         ...
]

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
   'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'basic': {
           'type': 'basic'
        }
    },
 }
```

**urls.py**

```
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="Food Delivery Application",
      default_version='0.1',
      description="Test description",
   ),
       public=True,
       permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending hours on my code, I finally made it working. `drf-yasg` won't work fine when its comes to overriding functions like `get_queryset()`and `get_serializer()` and filtering out the data of authenticated user using `self.request.user`  Use below coding technique to fix the issue:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if getattr(self, 'swagger_fake_view', False):
        return MyModel.objects.none()  # return empty queryset
    return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

To know more [click here](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/333#issuecomment-474883875)